# Can text that appears only on hover (visibility:hidden) be penalized by search engines (be considered hidden text, aka spam)?

Tags: mouseover

I am using the css code below for a large portion of the text on most pages for legitimate purposes, so that text is only visible when users hover over various images/links (to give the site more of a clean look). However, I recently learned that search engines may punish sites for what they consider to be hidden text. Does this only apply to conventional tricks like text that is the same color as the background, or could it apply to what I am doing here as well?

span.desc {
    line-height: 1.0em;
    visibility: hidden;
    font-size: 13px;
    display: block;
}

a:link, a:visited, a:hover span {
    visibility: visible;
    color: #040315;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
    display: block;
}